# How can I get past this exception involving jvisualvm with oc4j?

Tags: java, oc4j, jvisualvm

Every time I try to start the CPU profiler I get the following exception.  I have found reference to this exception in conjunction with Asian languages, but that is not the case here.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:323)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallAgentmain(InstrumentationImpl.java:348)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerActivate15.getArchiveFile(ProfilerActivate15.java:78)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerActivate15.activate(ProfilerActivate15.java:99)
    at org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server.ProfilerActivate15.agentmain(ProfilerActivate15.java:64)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and used the following instead
http://www.jvmmonitor.org/index.html